# Is it possible to buy advance monitoring sensors for a normal car?

Tags: automotive-design, aftermarket-upgrade

I was wondering if it is possible to buy some advance monitoring system and implement in a normal car. Monitoring systems like collision avoidance sensor, parking sensor, lane detector, and many more are only available in advanced and expensive cars. So is it possible to buy such systems separately and implement in a ordinary car. If any one has any idea please do let me know where i could get this..

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly buy parking sensors from various places - including major online retailers and auction sites. I'm not aware of any of the others having made it to the aftermarket scene yet, but I'm sure it will only be a matter of time...

Comment: Yes u are right I also came across the parking sensors and also the reverse camera but I was more interested in systems like Lane departure monitoring systems and Drowsiness detection but couldn't find anything.